# create customized transpose of data in python

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, transpose

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID  Month   Price   Sale
sk1 1       100     6
sk1 2       120     7
sk1 3       130     8
sk2 1       50      3
sk2 2       60      4
sk2 3       70      5
```

Desired output:

```
ID  1_Price 2_Price 3_Price 1_Sale  2_Sale  3_Sale
sk1 100     120     130     6       7       8
sk2 50      60      70      3       4       5
```

I tried pandas transpose with index option, but it's not giving desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) or [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), then flatten `MultiIndex` in columns by `list comprehension`:

```
df = df.set_index(['ID','Month']).unstack()
#alternative
#df = df.pivot('ID','Month')
df.columns = ['{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format(x) for x in df.columns]
#alternative
#df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)
print (df)
     1_Price  2_Price  3_Price  1_Sale  2_Sale  3_Sale
ID                                                    
sk1      100      120      130       6       7       8
sk2       50       60       70       3       4       5
```

And last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) + [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
    ID  1_Price  2_Price  3_Price  1_Sale  2_Sale  3_Sale
0  sk1      100      120      130       6       7       8
1  sk2       50       60       70       3       4       5
```

Comment: thanks, it seems, the ID is staying as index. how can i get ID as one of the columns?